# SQL Server get available time slots for a specific date range

Tags: c#, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I'm developing an appointment system for a medical firm that will allow viewing the available time slots in a specific date range (e.g. available time slots for today, or for tomorrow and so on) in which an appointment can be reserved for a patient.

Here are some critical things I want to clarify about the system:

1. Time slots are variant, that means I have some appointments that take 15 mins while others can take less or more time, it depends on the doctor's choice.
2. I have different rooms so more than one appointment can be booked at the same time, let's say it is allowed for 4 appointments at maximum (four rooms).

This system should be developed in C# and SQL Server on the database side.

- What is the best appointment table design which should serve this need? (I'm suggesting it should have the following, but correct me please):

  1. appointment_id
  2. appointment_start
  3. appointment_end
  4. patient_id
  5. doctor_id
  6. room_number
- can time-slots be found using only "appointment_start" and "appointment_end" columns?
- which one is a better practice: search for available time-slots in the sql server side or on the programming side? if it is better to be in the server side, can u please provide me a sample query for this?

Comment: Databases has been created to handle SQL queries so if you have SQL Server on a decent server - might use SQL for searching available time - slots. With the proper indexing - search would have a very good performance. Searching in the server leaves possibility to implement hash searching in the other hand.

Comment: I'm also curious whether a "Gaps and Islands" solution is better handled in SQL or the programming language, or a combination of both.  That kind of problem is easier to do in SQL if you're just dealing with dates. But it gets more complicated when dealing with datetime intervals that can overlap.